Solve the "word break problem" in a single line of code
Challenge
Solve this problem in the fewest number of bytes of code possible.
Write code that takes a string \$str\$ and a dictionary-list of words \$d\$ and finds all combinations of words from \$d\$ that, when concatenated together, result in \$str\$.
Example:
Given the string "wordbreakproblem" and the list ["this","th","is","famous","word","break","b","r","e","a","k","br","bre","brea","ak","problem"], the output should be:
[["word","b","r","e","a","k","problem"],["word","b","r","e","ak","problem"],
["word","br","e","a","k","problem"],["word","br","e","ak","problem"],
["word","bre","a","k","problem"],["word","bre","ak","problem"],
["word","brea","k","problem"],["word","break","problem"]]

Constraints and additional rules:
Each word in the dictionary \$d\$ as well as \$str\$ consists of ASCII letters in either full lower or upper case (your choice). There will always be at least one subset of \$d\$ that gives \$str\$ when concatenated. The order of the output does not matter, although each distinct output should occur exactly once.
Each word can only be used as many times as it appears in the input list. For example, "abba", ["a", "bba", "b"] should result in just [["a", "bba"]] even though abba can be formed by concatenating ["a","b","b","a"]. However, if the word list was instead ["a", "a", "bba", "b", "b"] then ["a","b","b","a"] would be included in the output.
Input and output format is flexible. Output can for example also be a list of space-delimited strings (e.g. ["word b r e a k problem","word b r e ak problem","word br e a k problem","word br e ak problem","word bre a k problem","word bre ak problem","word brea k problem","word break problem"]).
Test cases:
"wordbreakproblem", ["this","th","is","famous","word","break","b","r","e","a","k","br","bre","brea","ak","problem"] => [["word","b","r","e","a","k","problem"],["word","b","r","e","ak","problem"],["word","br","e","a","k","problem"],["word","br","e","ak","problem"],["word","bre","a","k","problem"],["word","bre","ak","problem"],["word","brea","k","problem"],["word","break","problem"]]
"abc", ["ab","bc","a","b","c"] => [["a","b","c"],["a","bc"],["ab","c"]]
"abcd", ["a","ab","bc","b","cd"] => [["a","b","cd"],["ab","cd"]]
"choices", ["c", "ch", "ce", "oi", "hoi","e", "s"] => [["c","hoi","ce","s"],["ch","oi","ce","s"],["ch","oi","c","e","s"]]
"cac", ["ca","c","a","c"] => [["c","a","c"],["ca","c"]]

I really would like to see a one-line C# answer.

Hi, welcome to CGCC. I see you've tagged it with c#, but usually it's best to open code-golf challenges up for all languages, and just mention something like "I really like to see a C# answer." or (if you have enough rep) "I offer a 50 bounty for a one-lined C# answer below X amount of bytes.". As for your question, "Is it possible to solve this problem in a single line of code?" related to C#, I'd say the answer is yes, since you could remove newlines in C# answers and have an entire complex program on a single line.. :/

May words be used more times than they appear in the word list? (i.e. should "abba", ["a", "bba", "b"] produce ["a bba"] or ["a bba", "a b b a"]? I imagine the former.)

If the input text may be produced in multiple ways using equal words appearing more than required (depending on the answer to the above) in the word list produce one or all ways (or would either be acceptable)? (e.g. assuming the answer to the above is ["a bba"] then given "abba", ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b"] how many "a b b a" should be in the resulting list, one or three (3-choose-2 = 3)? I imagine "one".)

I've edited your post to make it a more generic challenge and fix some formatting. If anything is now different than what you intended originally with your challenge, feel free to modify it again. Also, I've added a TODO to address both @JonathanAllan's comments above (before it can be re-opened). (I would assume the dictionary-words are a set of unique words, so the second comment wouldn't occur. And $str$="abba" | $d$=["a","bba","b"] would result in an empty output-list. That's just my assumption and how I would personally deal with those test cases, though.)

@KevinCruijssen "abba" is formable as "a"+"bba" so certainly not empty.

@JonathanAllan Woops, you're completely right. Mb. I still agree with your points in general, though. Ignore the small mistake in my comment. ;)

@KevinCruijssen Reply to "I'd say the answer is yes, since you could remove newlines in C# answers and have an entire complex program on a single line.. :/" Like how? Y Combinator?

@l4m2 What I meant was that newlines are mostly optional in C# programs. So even something like class Main{public static void Main(){Print("bla");}static void Print(string s){System.Console.WriteLine(s);}} may be multiple methods, but it's still a single line.. (But FWIW, I've also prepared a (very inefficient) single C# lambda that solves this challenge, which I will post if it gets reopened. And no, I haven't used a Y-combinator in that prepared lambda. I've actually just nested two parts, making the O-complexity and performance very bad and unusable in production, but it is golfed. )

@KevinCruijssen 1st version expilictly say The length of the string does not matter, but the ";" character is allowed only at the end.

I cleaned up the wording/formatting a bit and added some extra test cases to handle specific situations with repeated chars. Feel free to roll these edits back if they're not what you intended. You might also want to remove the "in a single line of code" from the title and explicitly state the [tag:code-golf] winning criterion of "solve this problem in the fewest bytes of code" (paraphrased)

@emanresu A Thank you. I think this formulation of the problem is quite appropriate. A one-line solution seems to be too cumbersome and redundant. The minimum number of bytes looks more rational.

I think it's worth emphasising that this is a nice first question - hopefully, downvoters will now remove or even reverse their votes to give it the recognition it deserves. Thanks also to both KevinCruijssen and emanresu for tending to it to get it up to par! Note that the sandbox over in meta exists to get questions ready for main, and there is the The Nineteenth Byte chatroom if you want to find people to help out.

Thank you very much.

Jelly,  10  6 bytes
ŒṖœ&ƑƇ

A monadic Link that accepts the target on the left and the word list on the on the right and yields a list of lists of words.
Try it online! (Footer prints each on its own line, space separated)
Or see the test-suite.
How?
ŒṖœ&ƑƇ - Link: Target; Wordlist
ŒṖ     - all partitions of {Target}
     Ƈ - keep those for which:
    Ƒ  -   is invariant under?:
  œ&   -     {Potential} multiset intersection {Wordlist}


I suppose this is the shortest possible solution.

Vyxal, 7 bytes
øṖ'⁰Þ∩⁼

Try it Online!
Port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer
øṖ      # Partitions
  '     # Where
      ⁼ # Remains the same under
   ⁰Þ∩  # (multiset) intersection with input


C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) with /u:System.Linq.Enumerable & /u:System.String flags, 243 236 214 212 bytes
w=>d=>{var t=w.SelectMany((_,j)=>w.Skip(j).Select((_,k)=>w.Substring(j,k+1))).Where(d.Contains);return Range(0,1<<t.Count()).Select(i=>t.Where((_,j)=>(i&1<<j)>0)).Where(e=>Concat(e)==w&e.All(d.ToList().Remove));}

-7 bytes thanks to @jdt, changing the .Equals(w) to ==w (which unlike Java in which I usually program, is fine in C# when comparing strings specifically) and another
-22 bytes thanks to @jdt simplifying getting all valid substrings for variable t
-2 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat (removing the parenthesis from i&(1<<j) - I should have checked operation precedence..)
Try it online.
Explanation:
Explanation in pseudo-code:

Generate all substrings of the given \$str\$, and only keep those that:

occurs in list \$d\$ †


Get all combinations of these substrings, and only keep those that:

joined together without delimiter is equal to \$str\$
all occur at least that many times in list \$d\$



w=>d=>{                      // Method with string and string-array parameters,
                             // and IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> result
  var t=                     //  Create a temp list
                             //  of all substrings of `w` that are present in `d`:
        w.SelectMany(        //   Flat-map over the characters of `w`:
           (_,j)=>           //    Only use the index within `w` as `j`:
             w.Skip(j)       //    Take `w` without its first `j` characters
              .Select(       //    Map over the remaining characters:
                (_,k)=>      //     Again only use the index as `k`:
                  w.Substring(j,k+1))
                             //      Take a substring of `w` starting at index `j` with a length of `k+1`
         ).Where(            //   After the flat-map, filter it by:
                 d.Contains);//    Only leave substrings that are present in `d`
  return                     //  Then return all combinations of valid substrings
                             //  where each valid substring is that many times available in `d`
                             //  and which concatenated are equal to string `w`:
    Range(0,1<<t.Count())    //   Create the range [0,2 to the power the size of `t`):
   .Select(i=>               //   Map those values to:
     t.Where(                //    Use `t`, filtered further by:
       (_,j)=>               //     Only use the index within `t` as `j`:
         (i&1<<j)>0))        //      Check whether (2 to the power `j`) bitwise-AND `i` is NOT 0
   .Where(e=>                //   Then filter this list of substrings:
     Concat(e)               //    Join them together without delimiter
      ==w                    //    and check whether this equals the given `w`
     &                       //    And also check that `e` doesn't use an item in `d` too many times:
      e.All(                 //     Check that all currently used substrings
            d.ToList().Remove));}
                             //     can one by one successfully be removed from a copy of `d`

Sources:

Get all substrings of a string is taken as a simplified version of this. Which is Range(0,w.Length).SelectMany(j=>Range(1,w.Length-j).Select(k=>w.Substring(j,k))) in my code. Now golfed by @jdt to w.SelectMany((_,j)=>w.Skip(j).Select((_,k)=>w.Substring(j,k+1)))
Combinations of List is taken from here. Which is Range(0,1<<t.Count()).Select(i=>t.Where((_,j)=>(i&1<<j)>0)) in my code.
List intersection with duplicated items is taken from here. Which modified to an All-check is e.All(d.ToList().Remove)) in my code.

† Limitation: since C# uses unsigned integers by default and I use 1<<t.Count() in my code, the maximum amount of valid substrings it can handle is 30, which will become 1073741824. One higher 1<<31 would be -2147483648, which gives incorrect results with the Range. This is also why I've added the .Where(s=>d.Contains(s)) even though it's redundant with the later e.All(d.ToList().Remove) check, since it otherwise wouldn't be able to handle the larger test case wordbreakproblem, reducing the amount of substrings 136 to the amount of valid substrings 16, and it would also time out for test case choices, reducing the amount of substrings 28 to the amount of valid substrings 8.

Suggests Concat(e)==w instead of Concat(e).Equals(w)

@jdt Aren't strings in C# also immutable? I must admit I don't program too often in C#, but in Java == instead of .equals on Strings can sometimes cause irregular behavior if references differ. I thought C# was similar in that regard, but maybe I misremember, since it's been about 10 years since I've used C# in my job.  EDIT: Seems like C# is similar to Java, so although == might sometimes work, but it's not guaranteed. Relevant SO answer. EDIT2: Or is the Interactive Compiler smarter than core .NET?

@jdt Nvm, I misread the SO answer I linked. It seems it's more lenient than Java, and in C# I can use == here. So thanks for the comment and bytes saved.

Suggests var t=w.SelectMany((_,j)=>w.Skip(j).Select((_,k)=>w.Substring(j,k+1))).Where(d.Contains);

@jdt Smart, thanks! That saved another 22 bytes. :)

Cool, was fun messing around with it :)

@ceilingcat Thanks. Should have checked operator precedence before just copy-pasting it from that SO answer.. :/

Charcoal, 76 bytes
ＳθＷＳ⊞υι≔⟦⟦⟦⟧υθ⟧⟧υＦυ¿§ι²ＦΦ§ι¹∧⁼λ⌕§ι¹κ¬⌕§ι²κ⊞υ⟦⁺§ι⁰⟦κ⟧Φ§ι¹⁻μ⌕§ι¹κ✂§ι²Ｌκ⟧⟦⭆¹§ι⁰

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
ＳθＷＳ⊞υι

Input the target string and list of words. (These bytes could be saved by taking the input in JSON format.)
≔⟦⟦⟦⟧υθ⟧⟧υＦυ

Start a breadth-first search with no words found so far, all of the words remaining, and the entire string remaining.
¿§ι²

If there is still string left to match, then...
ＦΦ§ι¹∧⁼λ⌕§ι¹κ¬⌕§ι²κ

... filtering on those words that are unique prefixes of the remainder, ...
⊞υ⟦⁺§ι⁰⟦κ⟧Φ§ι¹⁻μ⌕§ι¹κ✂§ι²Ｌκ⟧

Add the current word to the match list, remove one instance of it from the word list, remove it from the start of the string, and push the result to the search list.
⟦⭆¹§ι⁰

Otherwise, pretty-print the matched words.

05AB1E, 8 bytes
.œʒI1.;P

Inputs in the order \$str,d\$.
Pretty slow for large \$str\$, but it's still able to do all test cases simultaneously in about 35-40 seconds on TIO.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
.œ       # Get all partitions of the first (implicit) input-string `str`
  ʒ      # Filter this list of partitions by:
   I     #  Push the input-list `d`
    1.;  #  Replace each first occurrence of a value in `d` in the current
         #  partition by a 1
       P #  Product, to check if all parts in the partition are now 1s
         # (after which the remaining partitions are output implicitly as result)


Vyxal 3, 11 bytes
It's certainly not a marvel of efficiency.
ṖᵛṢ1⁾Ω“¹=}u

Vyxal It Online!
Explanation
ṖᵛṢ1⁾Ω“¹=}u­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
Ṗ            # ‎⁡Permutations of the dictionary
 ᵛṢ1⁾        # ‎⁢Sublists of those permutations
     Ω   }   # ‎⁣Filter sublists which:
      “      # ‎⁤  joined together,
       ¹=    # ‎⁢⁡  equal the input word.
          u  # ‎⁢⁢Only unique sublists.


Created with the help of Luminespire.

Japt, 12 bytes
à cá fÈ¬¶VÃâ

Try it
à cá fÈ¬¶VÃâ     :Implicit input of dictionary array U & target string V
à                :Combinations of U
  c              :Flat map
   á             :  Permutations
     f           :Filter
      È          :Through the following function
       ¬         :  Join
        ¶V       :  Equal to V?
          Ã      :End filter
           â     :Deduplicate


Python 3, 91 bytes
{t for i in range(len(d))for t in __import__("itertools").permutations(d,i)if"".join(t)==s}

Try it online!
Straightforward bruteforce. This is an expression which expects variables s (the word) and d (the wordlist) to already be defined, and produces the result as a set of tuples of strings.
The running time is horrendous; it's likely never going to finish the first test case, but it runs the rest pretty quickly.
